# how to set space at the beginning of input?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to set space at the beginning of input?
when I open input field with ng-model there, the text should have space between input beginning and text.
like shown on img

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a class to your input and give it padding. You could also do it on the input directly, but that would affect all input fields, so not sure if that's what you are looking for.

```css
 .space {
    padding-left: 10px
    }
```

```html
  <input class="space" type="text" value="Need space there">
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same in<textarea>? cannot do it.

Comment: Yes, works exactly the same. just add class="space" to your textarea.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding text-indent style will do..

```
<input type="text" style="text-indent:20px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `padding-left` `css` to give space between text and input.

```css
input{
  padding-left:10px
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="space ">
```